# How to retrieve two queries in single Data Factory Copy activity?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, change-tracking

Is it possible to use Azure Data Factory and retrieve 2 SELECT query statements in one Copy activity? One SELECT needs to be copied to the target, the other to an ADF variable. Or another solution?

Why do I need this? I am using SQL Server Change Tracking (CT) to copy only the changes. Microsoft advices there to use snapshot isolation and a transaction to get both the change data AND the current_change_version. So both need to be executed in the same query. See: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-snapshot-isolation). Two separate activities will have a delay in between, which can cause inconsistencies.

*I am aware of CDC, but I want to explicitly use CT

Answer (score 1):

Using a stored procedure in your `Copy Data` activity would enable you to do this.